Swift String Parser semicolon issues
i want to create an app that allows the user to edit user defaults which makes it free to silence the annoying update warnings but I have ran into an issue. The code should take a string and print a correct representation of it but my code struggles with semicolons, if you. run the code you should see the problem of semicolon in lists.
So everyone understand my code:
Single values should be printed like this:
myValue --> fsfsfsf
Lists should be printed like this:
LIST myList
-- value1234=gdwhgdqghdq
-- anotherone=1334
Here is my code:

let lookup = """
{
    AppleAccentColor = "-2";
    "Build History" =     {
        71031 = "2024-05-20 15:50:24 +0000";
    };
    "Editor Focus Mode" = 1;
    "Editor Focus Scope" = Text;
    "Editor Last Used Syntax Control" = 31;
    "Editor Syntax Control" = 31;
    "External Files Bookmarks" = {length = 219, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 000000a4 };
    "External Files Manual Order" =     (
    );
    "External Files Options" = 0;
    "Favorites Bookmarks" = {length = 219, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 000000a4 };
    "Favorites Manual Order" =     (
    );
    "Favorites Options" = 0;
    "First Launched Version" = "7.1.3";
    "Last Launched Build" = 71031;
    "Last Launched Version" = "7.1.3";
    "Library Locations Bookmarks" = {length = 219, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 000000a4 };
    "Library Locations Include Dropbox" = 0;
    "Library Locations Include Google Drive" = 0;
    "Library Locations Manual Order" =     (
    );
    "Library Locations Options" = 1;
    "Library Navigation History Items" = {length = 586, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 000001d4 };
    "Library Window Frame" = "{{498, 253}, {1230, 833}}";
    "Library Window State" = {length = 569, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 000001b7 };
    NSCloseAlwaysConfirmsChanges = 0;
    NSCloseAlwaysConfirmsChangesCustomized = 1;
    NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows = 1;
    NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindowsCustomized = 1;
    "NSSplitView Subview Frames Library Split View" =     (
        "0.000000, 0.000000, 118.000000, 833.000000, NO, NO",
        "119.000000, 0.000000, 230.000000, 833.000000, NO, NO"
    );
    "NSSplitView Subview Frames Split View" =     (
        "0.000000, 0.000000, 349.000000, 833.000000, NO, NO",
        "350.000000, 0.000000, 880.000000, 833.000000, NO, NO"
    );
    "Ping Installation Identifier" = "2B8719BA-0BB5-41BF-A616-C02B2BFA23BF-4407-0000005617A366C4";
    "Preview PDF Scale Configuration" = {length = 359, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 00000111 };
    "Stats Counter Values" = {length = 263, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 000000ca };
    "Version History" =     {
        "0.0" = "2024-05-20 15:50:24 +0000";
    };
}
"""

// Remove the first and last characters (curly braces)
var mutable = lookup
mutable.removeLast()
mutable.removeFirst()

// Remove all newlines and whitespaces
mutable = mutable.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
mutable = mutable.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

// Remove the last: ";"
mutable.removeLast()

// Split into segments
var segments = mutable.components(separatedBy: ";")

print(segments)

func parseKeyValue(from input: String) -> (key: String, value: String)? {
    guard let range = input.range(of: "=") else {
        return nil
    }
    let key = String(input[..<range.lowerBound]).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let value = String(input[range.upperBound...]).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    return (key: key, value: value)
}



// Print segments
for segment in segments {
    print("-----")
    if let keyvalues = parseKeyValue(from: segment) {
        
        // Determine between list of dictionary.
        
        if (keyvalues.value.hasPrefix("(") && keyvalues.value.hasSuffix(")")) || (keyvalues.value.hasPrefix("{") && keyvalues.value.hasSuffix("}")) || (keyvalues.value.hasPrefix("[") && keyvalues.value.hasSuffix("]")) {
            print("LIST: \(keyvalues.key)")
            var listContent = keyvalues.value
            listContent.removeFirst()
            listContent.removeLast()
            let values = listContent.split(separator: ",")
            for value in values {
                print("-- \(value)")
            }
        } else {
            print(keyvalues.key + "  -->  " + keyvalues.value)
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid format!")
    }
}

Update:
Thanks to Rob I was able to make this simple script which works, but doesn't really detect the dictionary.
import Foundation

let lookup = """
{
    "AppleAccentColor": "-2",
    "Build History": {
        "71031": "2024-05-20 15:50:24 +0000"
    },
    "Editor Focus Mode": 1,
    "Editor Focus Scope": "Text",
    ...
}
"""

guard let data = lookup.data(using: .utf8) else {
    fatalError("Failed to convert string to data")
}

do {
    if let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            print("-----")
            print("\(key) --> \(value)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Failed to deserialize JSON into a dictionary")
    }
} catch {
    print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
}


You saved the description of a NSDictionary (ie OpenStep Format), or that's what you are getting in console from the object? Because the NSData saved stuff can't be retrieve with just that String.

Clarify how you really get lookup, as you might encounter real issue there with data loss.

This looks like a string representation of a NSDictionary. It would be a lot easier to fetch it as a Dictionary (e.g. dictionaryRepresentation) and navigate that, rather than to try to manually parse it out from this string. So maybe we go back a step and discuss how you got this string and see if we can instead let UserDefaults give us the original dictionary.

@Rob this is just the standard console output of a defaults read com.example.app shell command

As pointed out by others the output is not JSON, it’s PropertyList. Read Data from disk and decode it with PropertyListSerialization to a [String:Any] dictionary.

The plist file of defaults read com.example.app should be at  ~/Library/Preferences/com.example.app.plist (for most ones, I guess? I don't know if there are other specific cases), so instead, read the Plist File as a Plist File from there, with PropertyListSerialization, there you shouldn't have lost data.

I sadly can't do that if there are exceptions and I would have to remove the App Sandbox for that to work

I don't know what's Library Navigation History Items value (which is (NS)Data, nor how it's coded, but currently you can't get it. Relying on description might be a bad idea, as we saw it when it previously shown the full data of (NS)Data. If you were able to skip these entries (with a Regex maybe), you could read the whole value easily. But in this case it's "easier" since there are no "nested" values.

At this point ia m thinking about just skipping the list stuff and just using the values that were given the the reliable plist serializer.

In a sandbox environment you can't read a foreign preference file with the shell either.
